# Unable to debug application in QtCreator

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I have problem with debugging Qt5.4 application on win7. It gives following error by message-Box (without debug mode, the application runs without any problem):

```
    The inferior stopped because it triggered an exception.
Stopped in thread 18 by: Exception at 0x7718c42d, code: 0xe06d7363: C++ exception, flags=0x1 (execution cannot be continued) (first chance).
```

call stack:

```
0   RaiseException  KERNELBASE      0x7718c42d  
1   DllGetClassObject   vsfilter        0x3a6aca71  
2   DirectVobSub    vsfilter        0x3a64fa11  
3   vsfilter            0x3a632c0b  
4   DllGetClassObject   vsfilter        0x3a6c90bc  
5   vsfilter            0x3a636da0  
6   CSTInnerUnknown::AddRef sync.cxx    225 0x753deddf  
7   DllGetClassObject   vsfilter        0x3a6aab2f  
8   CRWLock::AcquireReaderLock  rwlock_ole32.cxx    3099    0x753da471  
9   DllGetClassObject   vsfilter        0x3a6aab2f  
10  DllGetClassObject   vsfilter        0x3a6ce866  
11  DllGetClassObject   vsfilter        0x3a6cbd4b  
12  DispatchMessageWorker   USER32      0x759b77c4  
13  wcscpy_s    USER32      0x75a1a61d  
14  _RtlUserThreadStart ntdll       0x77919f45
```

Answer (score 1):

It might be a little bit late, but I had the same error.

See, I don't see your code, so I cant say what your problem was exactly but I can say what solved mine:

I had a Gaussian-filter of open-cv running, which was clearing my picture from noise. It had the size of 3x3. As soon as I adjusted the size to 10x10 for testing, I got the same exception.

So maybe you have also a to big filter or something. To say it exactly I would need more code example.

But anyway this maybe helps someone else!